# In my application I am trying to fetch specific user information from database using userID I am getting empty fields where I successfully stored it

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There is no error displaying in my app where is the problem
This is my code for retriving data:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fargment_profile, container, false);
    name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    mail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mail);
    phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    userID = user.getUid();
    //show all data
    ShowUser();
    return view;
}

private void ShowUser() {


    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                String username = snapshot.child(userID).child("name").getValue(String.class);
                String usermail = snapshot.child(userID).child("email").getValue(String.class);
                String userphone = snapshot.child(userID).child("phone").getValue(String.class);

                mail.setText(usermail);
                name.setText(username);
                phone.setText(userphone);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

This is my Firebase Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have issues with your reference.
**The code should be**

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users")
```

you are not referencing to the **users** node through this code `databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();`

It's better if you also add the user id in the databaseReference at the top so it will save you from mention  `snapshot.child(userID)` again and again

The code for reference till userId is :

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userID);
```

Final Code:

```
private void ShowUser() {
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(userID);

    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                String username = snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                String usermail = snapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                String userphone = snapshot.child("phone").getValue(String.class);

                mail.setText(usermail);
                name.setText(username);
                phone.setText(userphone);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Great answer Kamal!    @Irfan: to determine the userID, you'd use `String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUID();`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanku sir, It's great to have an appreciation from you. By the way, I forgot to simplify that piece of code.

Comment: Now the code is moving to else block to error Toast message and when I create new user and login with abc@gmail.com (shown in image) I am getting name, phone no. and email of new created user.

Comment: Authentication userid and the userid i am saving in database is not same when I store new user the id of previous and current get same.

Comment: @Irfan the userId will be same if you are retrieving it from the code 'String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUID();' . 
 And if your code is going to else section then it means your snapshot doesn't exist in database ( it means ,"USER_ID" of that particular user isn't in database.     Andd kindly elaborate your issue with logs and code so that I can help you with the exact solution.Feel free to ask if something is unclear in the answer .